# Change the label's font weight based on column

Tags: python, ggplot2, data-visualization

I've generated the following graph using ggplot for Python. The x axis represents days in the month of May.

[image]

Is there any way to highlight days that fall on a weekend? For example, make the label bold whenever the column `weekend == 1`?

I've tried using `aes` inside `theme` and `geom_text` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work? (code below)

[image: bold weekend in ggplot2]

```
by_day <- data.frame(
  X=0:6,
  weekday=0:6,
  variable="Number_of_tweets",
  value=c(5820,6965,7415,6800,5819,1753,1137))


# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=by_day, aes(x=weekday, y=value)) + 
            geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
            scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:6,
            labels=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"))

p + theme(axis.text=element_text(face=rep(c("plain", "bold"), c(5,2))))
```